# Lebesgue measure of an intersection of a sequence of subsets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is exercise 1.19 from "A User-Friendly Introduction to Lebesgue Measure and Integration" by Gail S. Nelson, and $m(E)$ is notation for Lebesgue measure of set $E$:

Let ${E_{k}}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable sets with $E_{1}\supseteq E_{2}\supseteq E_{3}\supseteq\ldots$. Define the set $E$ to be $E=\cap_{k=1}^{\infty}E_{k}$. If $m(E_{1})<\infty$, show that $m(E)=\lim_{k\to\infty}m(E_{k})$. Show by example that this need not to be the case if we remove the assumption that $m(E_{1})<\infty$.

My attempt of proof: Since $E$ is subset of $E_{k}$ for each $k$, then $m(E)\leq m(E_{k})$ - this is according to a theorem stating that Lebesgue measure of a subset is less or equal than Lebesgue measure of its superset. Thus, it's certainly true that $m(E)\leq\lim_{k\to\infty}m(E_{k})$ too. If the limit is 0, then $m(E)$ is equal to the limit, as Lebesgue measure of any set is greater or equal to zero.  However, now I don't see how to eventually prove that $m(E)$ cannot be less that the limit, in case when limit greater than 0.  Also, for the second part of the question, I cannot find a counter-example for the case when $m(E_{1})=\infty$.

Comment: @Calculon: What you said is correct, but it could be misleading the the OP since the wording "*this need not to be the case if we remove the assumption that* $m(E_1) < \infty$" does not claim that $m(E_1) < \infty$ is a necessary assumption.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You are right. I read it as if it was stated as a necessary condition. Sorry for the confusion, Crni

Comment: @Calculon: As you probably know, conditions that are not really necessary are sometimes stated in a way that say they are, and my first reaction to your comment was "good, I see someone is reading carefully". But then I looked closer at it myself . . . Incidentally, an example of what I'm talking about is when someone says that in order to determine the area of a rectangle, you need to know its length and its width. However, this is not true. You can find the area from its diagonal and length. For an even sillier example, you can find the area given the value of twice its area.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Not that this is the case here but I sometimes get confused by the two different meanings of a mathematical verbal expression, what mathematicians mean by that expression and what that expression means in the English language. Expressions like "if and only if", "necessary", "sufficient" fall into this category for me. I avoid using them as much as possible and instead go for A implies B type of language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If  $F_n:=E_n-E_{n+1}$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ then $E_k=E\cup\bigcup_{n=k}^{\infty}F_n$ and the sets in the union are disjoint, so that:

$$m(E_k)=m(E)+\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}m(F_n)$$

So if $m(E_{k_0})<\infty$ for some $k_0$ then $m(E)<\infty$ and $\sum_{n=k_0}^{\infty}m(F_n)<\infty$ and consequently: $$\lim_{k\to\infty}m(E_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\left[m(E)+\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}m(F_n)\right]=m(E)+\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}m(F_n)=m(E)$$

---

Counterexample will only work if $m(E_n)=\infty$ for *every* $n$. You could take $E_n=[n,\infty)$.

Comment: +1, slick proof. I mention for the benefit of others (since it took me a moment to recognize it) that the reason $\sum_{n=k_0}^{\infty}m(F_n) < \infty$ is because for $n \geq k_0$ we have $F_n \subseteq E_{k_0}$, and therefore $\bigcup_{n=k_0}^{\infty}F_n \subseteq E_{k_0}$. Since the set on the right hand side has finite measure, the inequality follows by countable additivity.

Comment: Very slick indeed, thanks for answering my question.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: can you explain why the counter example doesn't work? I suppose $m(E) = 0$, but the limit isn't 0?

Comment: @MaverickMeerkat I am not sure whether I understand your question. Do you mean the counterexample $E_n=[n,\infty)$? In that case the intersection is empty so that $m(E)=m(\varnothing)=0$. This while $m(E_n)=+\infty$ for *every* $n$. So we definitely do not have $\lim_{n\to\infty} m(E_n)=m(E)$.

Comment: How can one see/recognize that $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=k}^\infty m(F_n) = 0$?

Comment: @saper0 For $k>k_0$ we have:$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}m(F_n)=\sum_{n=k_0}^{\infty}m(F_n)-\sum_{n=k_0}^{k-1}m(F_n)$$Taking the limit for $k\to\infty$ we find:$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\cdots=\sum_{n=k_0}^{\infty}m(F_n)-\sum_{n=k_0}^{\infty}m(F_n)=0$$