# Measuable space

Tags: measure-theory

I have a problem with the following question:

> Let $(X, \mathscr{A})$ be a measusable space, and let $\mu$ be a measure on $(X, \mathscr{A})$. Let $\{A_n\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ be a decending sequence in $\mathscr{A}$. Set $A = \bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1} A_n$.
>
> Asumme that $\mu(A_n) \geq 1$ for all $n \geq 1$. Can you conclude that $\mu(A) \geq 1$? [Make a proof, or a counter example.]

Okay, so intuitively I think that this is false, but I can't quite find a way to make a proof or a why to make it clear. Can someone maybe give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Think about a counterexample in $\mathbb R$, or even $\mathbb Z$ with counting measure, and $\mu(A_n)=\infty$ for all $n$. (You might find it interesting to think whether the statement is true if some $A_n$ has finite measure.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your counterecample in ($\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}))$: $A_n=[n, +\infty)$. However, if $1\leq \mu(A_k)< +\infty$ for all $k$, then $\mu(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i)\geq 1$ is consequence of $\mu(\bigcap_{i=1}^{\infty} A_i)=lim_{i \to \infty}\mu(A_i)$. For proof look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1752900).