# Intersection of decreasing sequence of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In an exam, my teacher wrote [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752654/lebesgue-measure-of-an-intersection-of-a-sequence-of-subsets), I proved it in a similar way to the answer [in that post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752654/lebesgue-measure-of-an-intersection-of-a-sequence-of-subsets), but he pointed out to me that a step in the proof is wrong.

**What my teacher says**

Let $A_1 \supset A_2 \supset A_3 \supset \dots$ sequence of decreasing sets

We can construct the following sequence of disjoint sets

$B_1 = A_1 - A_2$

$B_2 = A_2 - A_3$

$B_3 = A_3 - A_4$

$\dots$

let $A = \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k$, then $A$ and $\cup_{k = N}^{\infty} B_k$ do not form a partition of $A_N$, are not disjoint, in fact $A$ is contained in the union $\cup_{k = N}^{\infty} B_k$.

But I think he is wrong, and I have this proof to prove that step.

**My proof**

$A_1 - \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k  = A_1 \cap (\cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k)^c = A_1 \cap (\cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k^c)$

The intersection is distributed over the union, then

$A_1 \cap (\cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k^c) = \cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (A_1 \cap A_k^c) = $

$= \emptyset \cup (A_1 - A_2) \cup (A_1 - A_3) \cup (A_1 - A_4) \cup ... = $

since the sequence is decreasing, finally

$= \emptyset \cup (A_1 - A_2) \cup (A_1 - A_3) \cup (A_1 - A_4) \cup ... = $

$= \emptyset \cup (A_1 - A_2) \cup (A_2 - A_3) \cup (A_3 - A_4) \cup ... =$

$= \cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k$

This is $A_1 - \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k  = \cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_k$.

The case $A_N - \cap_{k \in \mathbb{N}} A_k  = \cup_{k = N}^{\infty} B_k$ is analogous.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your teacher says that the sets $A,B_N,B_{N+1},\dots$ do not form a partition of $A_N$ then *he is wrong*.

It is evident that the sets $B_N, B_{N+1},\dots$ are disjoint.

Further if $x\in A$ then $x\in A_n$ for *every* $n$ implying, that no $n$ exists with $x\in B_n$.

This because $B_n\subseteq A_{n+1}^c$ by definition.

This makes it evident that the sets $A,B_N,B_{N+1},\dots$ are disjoint, and it is evident as well that their union coincides with $A_N$.

---

Your proof is correct and confirms that $A_N-A=\bigcup_{k=N}^{\infty}B_k$.

This combined with $A\subseteq A_N$ and disjointness of the $B_i$ (again) proves that $A,B_N,B_{N+1},\dots$ form a partition of $A_N$.

Answer (score 2):

Your teacher's claim that $A\subseteq \bigcup B_{k}$ is definitely wrong because if we assume that $x\in A$ then x lies in every $A_{k}$. So , if we assume, as the claim says, that lies in some $B_{m}$ then lies in $A_{m}/A_{m+1}$ which implies $x\notin A_{m+1}$ which is a contradiction. Your proof seems correct. I checked the claim $A_{1}/\bigcap_{1}^{\infty }A_{k}=\bigcup B_{k}$ using a proof of my own and I agree with your result. I suppose the other cases are also correct!